# Good video games for an Autistic 5th grader to encourage social skills

Tags: video-games, autism

**Disclaimer:**   *I realize that a lot of folks (including many professionals) think having autistic kids play games is moving them in the wrong direction (away from social interaction).  The friend below, who has both personal and professional experience in this, does think so. And I'd argue that if you can just shift an autistic child toward more social games (without increasing game time) would have little downside. And some folks feel that you should work on your strengths not your weaknesses.*

A friend of my runs an Autistm center and has an autistic 5th grader. I've noticed that he really craves social approval (he loves performing for an audience). But a lot of social interactions are just a bit too overwhelming to him while at the same time inscrutable (reading facial expressions).

So I was thinking that a video game (which he loves) where the interaction is rewarded (teams do better than individuals, etc.) but where that interaction is very explicit (chat instead of face to face conversations) might be a good "stepping stone" for him: Interaction that's not overwhelming but also easy to digest (more "literal").

He has access to a Wii, 3DS, and also internet on computer.

Comment: Clay, the majority of your questions on our site have been variations on "could you suggest some video games".  As you have been told repeatedly, suggestions for specific video games are *off topic* for our site.  Please stop posting these types of questions, and instead either keep the questions on topic, or ask in [chat]. I am closing this. If you can reword it to avoid asking for recommendations, and instead ask about the impact of games on children with Autism, we can see about reopening it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have direct experience but I have come across these resources:

- [Popchilla's World: A Game for Kids with Autism (pre-development)](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/2029331083/popchillas-world-a-game-for-kids-with-autism)
- [hacking autism](http://hackingautism.org/apps)
- [Google Play Android Apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=autism&c=apps&safe=2)

Good luck